# Parse hours from string with space delimiter

Tags: ruby, datetime, date-parsing

I have file strings that contain dates in their heading, stuff such as `2017-03-06 092328 - iPhone - Music Show - street performance, while walking the dog.m4a`

I would like to parse the date our of this string, because I need to print it in a podcast friendly format.

I'm able to parse out the date, but for some reason the time component refuses to be parsed out :)

```
Date.strptime("2017-03-06 092328", "%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S").strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S)
```

Expected output:

```
"2017-03-06 092328"
```

Actual output

```
"2017-03-06 000000"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `Date` is (what a surprise!) a date, as in, "Not a time, just a date".

```
require 'time'
Time.strptime("2017-03-06 092328", "%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
#=> "2017-03-06 09:23:28"
```

To be fair :

- the documentation of [`Time#strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) mentions that it's based on [`Date#strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime)
- `Date._parse("2017-03-06 09:23:28")` will happily return `{:hour=>9, :min=>23, :sec=>28, :year=>2017, :mon=>3, :mday=>6}`

If you find it confusing that a `Time` object has a date and a time but that `Date` just has a date, you could use [`DateTime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html).

Comment: ...or `DateTime.strptime("2017-...`. I prefer that to `Time.strptime("2017-...` only because I think it reads better.